# How to perform a beacon deposit for a new validator in a Custom Testnet?

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, staking, validators, lighthouse

I am trying to add a validator to an already running testnet

How can i make a beacon deposit, to allow that validator to start staking / validating blocks on the same testnet ?

Help appreciated!